# Sql: Add 2 or more text in one vaule

Tags: sql, database

I'm working on making a school management system and i'm stuck with the following problem: I need put the 2 parents' names up in the database so it would be in one column named `parent`.

I have tried this query, but it just says "0" with this code:

```
INSERT INTO Students (Name, Class, Birthday, Gender, Parent, Phone, Mail, Address)
VALUES ('Test', '1.B', '11-11-2001', 'Male', '$parent' + '&' + '$parent2', '12358912', 'test@mail.dk', 'Test 31');
```

Comment: What database are you inserting data into (e.g., MySQL, Oracle, etc.)? Are you executing this INSERT statement from some database client, or are you executing it using some driver for a particular programming language? The fact that your variables are prefaced with `$`, and the fact that your attempted string concatenation evaluates to `0` makes me think you're using PHP. (String concatenation in PHP should be done with a `.`, not a `+`, and you should be using parameterized queries when using variables to prevent SQL injection.)

Comment: Don't put "solved" in the title. Accept the answer to mark your question solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be how you do it

```
INSERT INTO Students (Name, Class, Birthday, Gender, Parent, Phone, Mail, Address)
VALUES ('Test', '1.B', '11-11-2001', 'Male', $parent & $parent2, '12358912', 'test@mail.dk', 'Test 31');
```

(Take off your quotes, as these are string variables now, not string literals)

Although I would add a space character too: as in

```
INSERT INTO Students (Name, Class, Birthday, Gender, Parent, Phone, Mail, Address)
VALUES ('Test', '1.B', '11-11-2001', 'Male', $parent &' '& $parent2, '12358912', 'test@mail.dk', 'Test 31');
```

But it depends on your database system (syntax) etc